# Convert Faster RCNN Inception V2 .pb file to .tflite?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I cannot able to find any script of converting Faster RCNN Inception v2 (trained using TensorFlow Object API) into .tflite.

Does any one has worked on this ?
Suggestion to convert ?

Comment: Please provide details on what is happening, and what errors you are encountering, so we can help you

Comment: @karim I m trying to convert pretrained FRCNN Inception v2 model to .tflite
Script -- !tflite_convert \ --graph_def_file="frozen_inference_graph.pb" \ --output_file="model.tflite" \ --input_shapes=1,1024,576,3 \ -- input_arrays=image_tensor \
--inference_input_type=QUANTIZED_UINT8 \
--mean_values=128 \
--std_dev_values=127 \
--output_arrays=detection_classes,detection_boxes,detection_scores
--allow_custom_ops\
i was able to convert the model to .tflite format. At time of Infer # facing error - RuntimeError: Encountered unresolved custom op: Enter.Node number 1 (Enter) failed to prepare.